# PHP extension via CLI works but not through apache

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface

Here is the scenario I have... I have library from a vendor that does encryption/decryption as part of a product we use (no idea how it works under the hood).  I built a PHP extension and everything works brilliantly via the CLI.  Here is the raptor.c file I wrote for the PHP extension:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include "php.h"

//#if HAVE_LIBRAPTOR
#include "php_raptor.h"
#include "raptor.h"

#include "ext/standard/info.h"

/* If you declare any globals in php_raptor.h uncomment this:
ZEND_DECLARE_MODULE_GLOBALS(raptor)
*/

/* True global resources - no need for thread safety here */
static int le_raptor;

/* {{{ raptor_functions[]
 *
 * Every user visible function must have an entry in raptor_functions[].
 */
const zend_function_entry raptor_functions[] = {
        PHP_FE(raptor_decNK,                 NULL)
        PHP_FE(raptor_encNK,                 NULL)
        {NULL, NULL, NULL}      /* Must be the last line in raptor_functions[] */
};
/* }}} */

/* {{{ raptor_module_entry
 */
zend_module_entry raptor_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
        STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
        "raptor",
        raptor_functions,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        PHP_MINFO(raptor),
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
        "0.1", /* Replace with version number for your extension */
#endif
        STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};
/* }}} */

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_RAPTOR
ZEND_GET_MODULE(raptor)
#endif

/* {{{ PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION
 */
PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(raptor)
{
        php_info_print_table_start();
        php_info_print_table_header(2, "raptor API support", "enabled");
        php_info_print_table_end();

}
/* }}} */


PHP_FUNCTION(raptor_decNK) {
  char * enctext;
  unsigned char * dectext;
  int enctextsize;
  size_t dectextsize;

  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &enctext, &enctextsize) == FAILURE) {
    RETURN_NULL();
  }

  dectext = decNK((unsigned char *) enctext, (size_t) enctextsize, &dectextsize);

  if (dectext == NULL) {
    RETURN_FALSE;
  } else {
    RETURN_STRINGL((char *) dectext, dectextsize, 1);
  }
}

PHP_FUNCTION(raptor_encNK) {
  char * dectext;
  unsigned char * enctext;
  int dectextsize;
  size_t enctextsize;

  if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &dectext, &dectextsize) == FAILURE) {
    RETURN_NULL();
  }

  enctext = encNK((unsigned char *) dectext, (size_t) dectextsize, &enctextsize);

  if (enctext == NULL) {
    RETURN_FALSE;
  } else {
    RETURN_STRINGL((char *) enctext, enctextsize, 1);
  }
}


//#endif
```

and the applicable pieces of the vendor's raptor.h file:

```
unsigned char *decNK(unsigned char * s, size_t inLen, size_t * outLen);
unsigned char *encNK(unsigned char * s, size_t inLen, size_t * outLen);
```

My test.php file has really simple code:

```
<?php
$x = 1;
echo "$x\n";
$y = raptor_encNK($x);
echo "$y\n";
$x = raptor_decNK($y);
echo "$x\n";
?>
```

From the CLI I get (output $y changes with each run, but final output always correct)

```
# /usr/local/bin/php -f /usr/local/var/htdocs/test.php
1
FL//haHZgltG
1
```

The same code through the browser gets (again output $y changes, final output always crap)

```
1
TgPw72NF9Zby
<binary crap>
```

So I'm thinking something is getting lost in translation when it goes to Apache... or I have screwed up the extension and can't figure it out... or maybe both.  I just don't understand why it would work via the CLI and not via Apache.

Comment: PHP CLI and PHP Apache might have different INI files. Check the configuration and look for the difference.

Comment: Obvious point, and I'm sure the answer is yes, but - are your testing this on the same system? Also, how is PHP running under Apache (module, CGI)? Also, probably won't matter, but what OS?

Comment: Yes, testing on the same system (Solaris 10).  PHP is an apache module (PHP compiled with --with-apxs2=/usr/local/sbin/apxs).  PHP 2.3.6 and Apache 2.2.17.  According to phpinfo() and bin/php -i both are loading /usr/local/etc/php.ini-production (--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc was used during build)

Comment: So I got a debugging build of the library from the vendor and while working with them it seems the issue has to do with size_t used in a function for cryptographic rotation(?).  Calling from the application, the PHP CLI, PERL script (connected to the library via a PERL module) it works perfectly.  When called through Apache apparently size_t is changed.  Still trying to figure out why.  Anyone have any guesses?

Answer (score 1):

So in the end it wasn't an issue with size_t but the size of an integer within their code.  There is still mass confusion as to why it works when called by the CLI versus using Apache and a web browser... I may never find out.

Answer (score 0):

What does the apache error_log report? That's almost certainly where you'll find a clue to the cause.

Personally, I'd suspect a permissions problem - remember that the apache user has very limited permissions - certainly more restrictive than yours at the command line.

Comment: The apache error log says nothing... and I've even cranked the log level to debug hoping that would show something. I did su - into the apache user and validated I can read and execute the CLI with no issue (and I even chmod'd 777 down the tree and restarted apache to make sure)... unfortunately there was no change.